# List databases and tablespace in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How I can list all databases in `SQL Server 2014` and table space size for each one?

I tested this query

```
EXEC sp_spaceused null, false
```

But I get only result for one database.

Comment: The reason you only got one record back is because sp_spaceused is per database.  It will return the information for whichever database you are running it against.

Answer (score 8):

[The undocumented sp_MSforeachdb procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678274/list-databases-and-tablespace-in-sql-sevrer-2014)   can loop all database but have some limitation.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_spaceused null, false'
```

Comment: [`sp_msforeachdb` is a terrible idea](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

Comment: sp_msforeachdb has size limits, like number of databases in the instance. Bad idea!

Comment: @Giova Reading through the code of `sp_MSforeachdb` it seems to be doing a rather simple cursor over the databases. Could you elaborate a bit on the 'size limits' ? (PS: not that I like the sp very much, for starters it uses a global cursor and frankly it's code looks terrible, but historically that's been true for most MS system sp's although I'm under the impression it's improving with each new version)

Comment: @deroby: the big limit is that in the following syntax:  EXEC sp_MSforeachdb "@command1"='use ?; exec sp_changedbowner ''sa''' -- Change all DBs to "sa" owner   The max size of "@command1" is 2000 characters. Read this for other issues: https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2

Comment: Although I agree that 2000 chars isn't all that much, it should do for eg "sp_changedbowner". Don't get me wrong, just like you did I have written my own version of the stored procedure many years ago (on SQL7 and tbh.: I only found out about the MS version much later), and off course my own version is tweaked to my needs over the years so I've not used the MS version in ages. But the fact that `command1` is 'only' 2000 characters is a rather strange motivation IMHO (a simple sp_help' tells me this would be the case so it's not a surprise); seems even MS realised that and added `command2`...

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible to do everything with one SQL query?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      database_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    , data_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
    , log_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space (database_id, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          DB_ID()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8. / 1024)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #table

CREATE TABLE #table (
      database_id INT
    , obj_name NVARCHAR(1000)
    , total_rows INT
    , total_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , used_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , unused_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , index_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , data_space DECIMAL(18,2)
)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #table
    SELECT 
          DB_ID()
        , s.name + ''.'' + o.name
        , i.total_rows
        , total_space = i.total_pages * 8. / 1024
        , used_space = i.used_pages * 8. / 1024
        , unused_space = (i.total_pages - i.used_pages) * 8. / 1024
        , index_space = i.index_pages * 8. / 1024
        , data_space = data_pages * 8. / 1024
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    JOIN (
        SELECT
              i.[object_id]
            , total_pages = SUM(a.total_pages)
            , used_pages = SUM(a.used_pages)
            , index_pages = SUM(a.used_pages - CASE WHEN a.[type] != 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id IN (0, 1) THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0 END) 
            , data_pages = SUM(CASE WHEN a.[type] != 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id IN (0, 1) THEN a.data_pages END)
            , total_rows = SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id IN (0, 1) AND a.[type] = 1 THEN p.[rows] END)
        FROM sys.indexes i
        JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
        WHERE i.is_disabled = 0
            AND i.is_hypothetical = 0
        GROUP BY i.[object_id]
    ) i ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = ''U''
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT
      d.name
    , t.total_size
    , t.data_size
    , s.data_used_size
    , t.log_size
    , s.log_used_size
    , tt.*
FROM (
    SELECT
          database_id
        , log_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , data_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , total_size = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    FROM sys.master_files
    GROUP BY database_id
) t
JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = t.database_id
LEFT JOIN #space s ON d.database_id = s.database_id
LEFT JOIN #table tt ON t.database_id = tt.database_id
ORDER BY t.total_size DESC, tt.total_space DESC
```

output -

```
name             total_size    data_size   data_used_size   log_size    log_used_size   database_id obj_name               total_rows  total_space     used_space    unused_space   index_space   data_space
---------------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ----------- --------------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------- --------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- -----------------
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.Posts              21736594    49695.45        49452.38      243.08         157.95        49294.43
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.Comments           36585420    11879.19        11877.70      1.48           44.21         11833.49
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.Votes              67258370    2419.73         2419.38       0.35           9.03          2410.35
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.Badges             12783309    619.26          619.15        0.11           2.30          616.84
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.Users              3473095     411.78          410.66        1.12           1.53          409.13
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.PostLinks          2271053     72.76           72.70         0.05           0.28          72.42
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.LinkTypes          2           0.02            0.02          0.00           0.01          0.01
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.VoteTypes          15          0.02            0.02          0.00           0.01          0.01
StackOverflow    66339.88      65840.00    65102.06         499.88      4.94            24          dbo.PostTypes          8           0.02            0.02          0.00           0.01          0.01
```

Comment: Why do you create #space? Is there any solution without temporary table?

Comment: Is there any other solution? I don't need to store the data into table. I need just to print it.

Comment: Сan be a lot solutions for your situation. What you want to receive as a result?

Comment: Do you know diff between `table` and `#table`? If you want just enum data use a dynamic sql

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm new to MS SQL

Comment: I need to execute every 3 seconds SQL query to display databases size. What will be the best solution for this?

Comment: Again... What you need database size or + table size?

Comment: Yes, I need database size and table size. Everything useful is useful.

Comment: `table size` - only data, data + index, ... ?

Comment: Everything possible will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Databases -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      database_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    , data_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
    , log_used_size DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space (database_id, data_used_size, log_used_size)
    SELECT
          DB_ID()
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN space_used END)
        , SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN space_used END)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.[type], space_used = SUM(FILEPROPERTY(s.name, ''SpaceUsed'') * 8. / 1024)
        FROM sys.database_files s
        GROUP BY s.[type]
    ) t;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT
      d.database_id
    , d.name
    , t.total_size
    , t.data_size
    , s.data_used_size
    , t.log_size
    , s.log_used_size
FROM (
    SELECT
          database_id
        , log_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 1 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , data_size = CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [type] = 0 THEN size END) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
        , total_size = CAST(SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 AS DECIMAL(18,2))
    FROM sys.master_files
    GROUP BY database_id
) t
JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = t.database_id
LEFT JOIN #space s ON d.database_id = s.database_id
ORDER BY t.total_size DESC
```

Tables -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#space') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #space

CREATE TABLE #space (
      database_id INT
    , obj_name NVARCHAR(1000)
    , total_rows INT
    , total_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , used_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , unused_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , index_space DECIMAL(18,2)
    , data_space DECIMAL(18,2)
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
    USE [' + d.name + ']
    INSERT INTO #space
    SELECT 
          DB_ID()
        , s.name + ''.'' + o.name
        , i.total_rows
        , total_space = i.total_pages * 8. / 1024
        , used_space = i.used_pages * 8. / 1024
        , unused_space = (i.total_pages - i.used_pages) * 8. / 1024
        , index_space = i.index_pages * 8. / 1024
        , data_space = data_pages * 8. / 1024
    FROM sys.objects o
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    JOIN (
        SELECT
              i.[object_id]
            , total_pages = SUM(a.total_pages)
            , used_pages = SUM(a.used_pages)
            , index_pages = SUM(a.used_pages - CASE WHEN a.[type] != 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id IN (0, 1) THEN a.data_pages ELSE 0 END) 
            , data_pages = SUM(CASE WHEN a.[type] != 1 THEN a.used_pages WHEN p.index_id IN (0, 1) THEN a.data_pages END)
            , total_rows = SUM(CASE WHEN i.index_id IN (0, 1) AND a.[type] = 1 THEN p.[rows] END)
        FROM sys.indexes i
        JOIN sys.partitions p ON i.[object_id] = p.[object_id] AND i.index_id = p.index_id
        JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
        WHERE i.is_disabled = 0
            AND i.is_hypothetical = 0
        GROUP BY i.[object_id]
    ) i ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = ''U''
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0;'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT DB_NAME(t.database_id), *
FROM #space t
```

Comment: Is it possible to do everything with one SQL query?

Comment: @Peter Penzov check another answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following query to list for each database the size for each filegroup (TABLESPACE). Just one command and no explicit use of tempdb:

```
DECLARE @database_id int 
DECLARE @database_name sysname 
DECLARE @sql_string nvarchar(2000) 
DECLARE @file_size TABLE 
    ( 
    [database_name] [sysname] NULL, 
    [groupid] [smallint] NULL, 
    [groupname] sysname NULL, 
    [fileid] [smallint] NULL, 
    [file_size] [decimal](12, 2) NULL, 
    [space_used] [decimal](12, 2) NULL, 
    [free_space] [decimal](12, 2) NULL, 
    [name] [sysname] NOT NULL, 
    [filename] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL 
    )
SELECT TOP 1 @database_id = database_id 
    ,@database_name = name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id > 0 
ORDER BY database_id
WHILE @database_name IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @sql_string = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@database_name) + CHAR(10) 
    SET @sql_string = @sql_string + 'SELECT 
                                        DB_NAME() 
                                        ,sysfilegroups.groupid 
                                        ,sysfilegroups.groupname 
                                        ,fileid 
                                        ,convert(decimal(12,2),round(sysfiles.size/128.000,2)) as file_size 
                                        ,convert(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(sysfiles.name,''SpaceUsed'')/128.000,2)) as space_used 
                                        ,convert(decimal(12,2),round((sysfiles.size-fileproperty(sysfiles.name,''SpaceUsed''))/128.000,2)) as free_space 
                                        ,sysfiles.name 
                                        ,sysfiles.filename 
                                    FROM sys.sysfiles 
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sysfilegroups 
                                        ON sysfiles.groupid = sysfilegroups.groupid'

    INSERT INTO @file_size 
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql_string   
    SET @database_name = NULL 
    SELECT TOP 1 @database_id = database_id 
        ,@database_name = name 
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE database_id > @database_id 
    ORDER BY database_id 
END
SELECT database_name,  ISNULL(groupname,'TLOG') groupname, SUM(file_size) as filegroup_size, SUM(space_used) as space_used, SUM(free_space) as free_space 
FROM @file_size 
GROUP BY database_name, groupid, groupname
```

Output:

```
database_name       groupname   file_size   space_used  free_space
AdventureWorksLT    TLOG    18.00   1.03    16.97
AdventureWorksLT    PRIMARY 21.00   5.88    15.13
t_Temp              TLOG    64.94   3.79    61.15
t_Temp              PRIMARY 3867.00 1947.38 1919.63
t_Temp              fg1 3.00    0.31    2.69
t_Temp              fg2 3.00    0.31    2.69
t_Temp              fg3 3.00    0.31    2.69
t_Temp              fg4 3.00    0.31    2.69
CSB                 TLOG    10.00   1.11    8.89
CSB                 PRIMARY 25.00   2.50    22.50
CSB                 DATA    25.00   2.63    22.38
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query we are using in our environment to find the size of each DB.             Check out whether it is helpful in your case.

```
SELECT dbfile.NAME          AS DatabaseFileName, 
       dbfile.size / 128    AS FileSizeInMB, 
       sysFG.NAME           AS FileGroupName, 
       dbfile.physical_name AS DatabaseFilePath 
FROM   sys.database_files AS dbfile 
       INNER JOIN sys.filegroups AS sysFG 
               ON dbfile.data_space_id = sysFG.data_space_id
```

Comment: OOPS, you want the information in Oracle or SQL Server ? you tagged your question under SQL Server.

Comment: Can you add some more information into this query. Anything useful.

Comment: Can you let me know what and all you want to see in the result.

Comment: What information available in SQL Server? Can you add `total_size    data_size   data_used_size   log_size    log_used_size   database_id obj_name               total_rows  total_space     used_space    unused_space   index_space   data_space`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply get database names and total size as follows:

```
select db.name, SUM(size) * 8. / 1024 as totalsize
from master..sysdatabases db 
inner join sys.master_files dbf on db.dbid=dbf.database_id 
group by db.name
```

Comment: Can you extent the SQL query with more data?

Comment: For example can you add `total_size    data_size   data_used_size   log_size    log_used_size   database_id obj_name               total_rows  total_space     used_space    unused_space   index_space   data_space`?

Comment: In this statement is missing the filegroup dietail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query in order to check the table spaces in  Sql server
I used it in Sql server 2012  and it work fine, but I think It Work in any version.

Please let me know if is useful for you.

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME  "Table Name",
    s.Name  "Schema Name",
    p.rows  "RowCounts",
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8  "Total Space KB", 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8  "Used Space KB", 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8  "UnusedSpaceKB"
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: Can you extend SQL query with additional information like database name data file and etc?

Answer (score 0):

Full copy of `sp_spaceused` functionality -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    [db_name] SYSNAME PRIMARY KEY,
    database_size_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
    unallocated_space_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
    reserved_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
    data_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
    index_size_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
    unused_mb DECIMAL(18,2),
)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT '
USE [' + d.name + ']

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT DB_NAME(),
       database_size = (dbsize + logsize) * 8. / 1024,
       unallocated_space = CASE WHEN dbsize >= reservedpages THEN (dbsize - reservedpages) * 8. / 1024 ELSE 0 END,
       reserved = reservedpages * 8. / 1024,
       data = pages * 8. / 1024,
       index_size = (usedpages - pages) * 8. / 1024,
       unused = (reservedpages - usedpages) * 8. / 1024
FROM (
    SELECT dbsize = SUM(CASE WHEN status & 64 = 0 THEN size END),
           logsize = SUM(CASE WHEN status & 64 <> 0 THEN size END)
    FROM dbo.sysfiles
) t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT reservedpages = SUM(a.total_pages),
           usedpages = SUM(a.used_pages),
           pages = SUM(
               CASE
                   WHEN it.internal_type IN (202, 204, 207, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 221, 222, 236) THEN 0
                   WHEN a.[type] <> 1 AND p.index_id < 2 THEN a.used_pages
                   WHEN p.index_id < 2 AND it.is_ms_shipped = 0 THEN a.data_pages
                   ELSE 0
               END
           )
    FROM sys.partitions p
    JOIN sys.allocation_units a ON p.[partition_id] = a.container_id
    JOIN sys.objects o ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN sys.internal_tables it ON p.[object_id] = it.[object_id]
) t1'
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.[state] = 0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Output -

```
db_name                database_size_mb      unallocated_space_mb   reserved_mb        data_mb       index_size_mb      unused_mb
---------------------- --------------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ------------- ------------------ ----------------
AdventureWorks2012     279.25                47.24                  189.76             3.38          175.56             10.81
distribution           7.00                  1.87                   3.13               0.16          2.53               0.44
locateme               1050.13               588.33                 2.67               0.05          2.17               0.45
mail                   8.00                  2.96                   3.04               0.14          2.41               0.49
master                 554.00                487.78                 4.28               0.44          3.22               0.63
model                  7.13                  1.78                   2.28               0.04          1.88               0.37
msdb                   46.44                 1.20                   19.05              5.80          12.13              1.12
sql-format.com         126.39                1.06                   124.31             116.35        7.25               0.71
Refactoring            494.32                57.90                  308.54             0.17          307.25             1.12
StackOverflow          66339.88              739.06                 65100.94           6996.23       57858.06           246.65
tempdb                 9.50                  5.49                   2.51               0.05          2.07               0.39
```

Output ( `EXEC [sql-format.com].sys.sp_spaceused` ) -

```
database_name       database_size      unallocated space
------------------- ------------------ ------------------
sql-format.com      126.39 MB          1.06 MB

reserved     data        index_size   unused
------------ ----------- ------------ ------------------
127296 KB    125376 KB   1192 KB      728 KB
```

Answer (score 0):

To display data and log space information for a database.

Check this link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190674.aspx#Anchor_1